# Angular AOT unknown identifier undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, angular-aot

I'm trying to run AOT compilation on my Angular project but when I run the command

```
"./node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: Internal error: unknown identifier undefined
    at Object.importExpr$$1 [as importExpr] (..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24071:23)
    at tokenExpr ..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18428:39)
    at providerDef (..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18331:20)
    at ..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18548:77
    at Array.map (native)
    at NgModuleCompiler.compile (..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18548:44)
    at AotCompiler._compileModule (..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24004:32)
    at ..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23916:66
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at AotCompiler._compileImplFile (..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23916:19) Compilation failed
```

How can I know in which file the error is and what is the error?

Comment: Do you have a reproduction of this issue?

Comment: @yurzui What do you mean by reproduction? This is a quite large project, based on Jhipster, and I don't know where to start debbuging

Comment: Seriously how do one debug this issue in a big app? The error should have more information. @PauloHenriquedeSiqueira how did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem recently for us it was a missing *Location* import from the *@angular/common* module.